# char * and integers, can you convert between?

Tags: c, pointers

why cant I do this:

```
char * p = (char *) 48;
printf("%d", p[0]); // why doesn't this give me 4
```

but I can do this:

```
char p = 48;
printf("%d", p);
```

thanks

Comment: Pointers are not chars, and the internal byte representation of 48 cast as as a char* is not as you seem to think it is.

Comment: Because 48 isn't a char*?

Comment: It can be, but as pointed out by AlexD below, you cannot just pick integers out of the pointer representation, print them and expect defined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot convert between integers and pointers in a reliable way.

According to the standard:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
>
> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer
>   type.

**P.S.** This answers the question in the title: "*char * and integers, can you convert between?*". Regarding the question "*why doesn't this give me 4*", see **@DorianAmouroux**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312695/3246555).

Answer (score 2):

Because `(char *)48` means that you cast an integer into a pointer value.

To store a number in a string variable, you have to do this:

```
char p[] = "48";
```

Or with a `malloc`:

```
char *p = strdup("48");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the size of your variables. On a 64-bit system, the size (in bytes) of pointers are 8 bytes. For example,

```
int a = 5;
int* b = &a;
std::cout << sizeof(a) << std::endl; // prints 4
std::cout << sizeof(b) << std::endl; // prints 8
```

This means that the type int is represented by 4 bytes on my system, i.e. 32 bits. Hence, the largest value that may be stored in an integer is

```
2^31 - 1 = 2147483647
```

8 bytes means 64 bits. Therefore, we cannot do

```
// error: cast from 'int*' to 'int' loses precision
int c = (int)b;
```

However, we can do

```
unsigned long long d = (unsigned long long)b;
```

because

```
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned long long) << std::endl;
```

prints 8. Therefore, no precision is lost.

```
std::cout << d << std::endl; // prints 2358852
std::cout << b << std::endl; // prints 0x23fe44 which is 2358852 in hexadecimal representation.
```

Pointer to integer representation is done all the time in the native Win32 API. The header of a window procedure (window callback function) is

```
LRESULT __stdcall wndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

WPARAM is a typedef for an unsigned integer which has size (in bytes) 8.
Therefore, you would see all the time code like

```
char buffer[256];
SendMesssage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, 256, (LPARAM) buffer);
```

Notice the conversion from pointer to LPARAM in the last argument.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You CAN convert between pointers and integers, when they have the same size.